# Armed with the information that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$, evaluate: $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z^2)}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, complex-numbers

**Armed with the information that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$, evaluate: $(i)\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z^2)}{z}, (ii) \lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{f(z^2+1)}{z-i}$ .**

For $(i)$ let $u:=z^2$ be so $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z^2)}{z}=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{u}\frac{f(u)}{u}=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{u}\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(u)-f(0)}{u-0}=0\cdot f'(0)=0\cdot 1=0$ Is this argument well? could you do the same with $(ii)$? thanks for your help.

Comment: I would avoid writing things like $\sqrt u$.

Comment: I think it's good. Do similar for ii.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why?

Comment: @MyGlasses that substitution if it can be done if the function is not injective?

Comment: @MyGlasses "Do similar[ly] for (ii)"? How do you let $u=z^2$ when $z\to i$ and then write $\sqrt{u}$ without asking yourself deep questions about what you end up doing?

Comment: @ClementC. With $z-i=w$ see
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{f(z^2+1)}{z-i}=\lim_{w\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(w^2+2iw)}{w^2+2iw}(w+2i)=2i$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use L'Hospital rule
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(z^2)}{z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{2zf'(z^2)}{1}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{f(z^2+1)}{z-i}=2i.$$

Comment: L'Hopital rule true for complex functions??

Comment: @Jack Ok. L'Hopital's rule is true when the function is analytic. Here the function is analtytic about $z=1$ so we can use this rule.

Comment: I must be daft. Why is it analytic? (the assumptions on $f$ from the OP are pretty fuzzy to me...)

Comment: It is differentiable in $1$ since the problem says $f'(0)=1$ and this means there are $\infty$ differentiable about $z=0$, that's analytic. I think it sufficient to accept analyticity of $f$

Comment: Differentiability at a single point is different from being analytic. I think being analytic requires an open set and not a point. Moreover the limits in question are easily evaluated using algebraic manipulation from the given data, so using advanced tools like analytic function and L'Hospital's Rule are an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know is that the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable again. By $f(0)=0$ the both limits are just the differential quotient of $z\mapsto f(z^2)$ and $z\mapsto f(z^2+1)$ at the point $z_0=0$ and $z_0=\mathrm i$. Hence the limits are (by the chain rule) $0$ and $2\mathrm i$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f'(0)=1$ is same as saying $(f(z)-f(0))/z\to 1$ as $z\to 0$. Thus we have $f(z) /z\to 1$ as $z\to 0$. Then $f(z^{2})/z=z\cdot f(z^{2})/z^{2}\to 0\cdot 1=0$.

Let $w=z^{2}+1$ so that $w\to 0$ as $z\to i$. Then $$\frac{f(z^{2}+1)}{z-i}=\frac{f(w)}{w}\cdot (z+i) \to 1\cdot 2i=2i$$ as $z\to i$.